# Running rust on Docker: Empty reply from server

Tags: docker, rust

I'd like to run a rust web app in a docker container. I'm new to both technologies so I've started out simple.

Here is `main.rs`:

```
extern crate iron; 
use iron::prelude::*; 
use iron::status; 
fn main() { 
    fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Hello World!"))) 
    } 
    Iron::new(hello_world).http("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap(); 
}
```

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "docker"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
iron = "*"
```

`Dockerfile` (adapted from [this](https://blog.clementmiao.com/firs-steps-with-rust-part-2-bf70760efa99) tutorial)

```
FROM jimmycuadra/rust

EXPOSE 8080
COPY Cargo.toml /source
COPY src/main.rs /source/src/
CMD cargo run
```

These are the commands I ran:

1. `docker build -t oror/rust-test`
2. `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm -v $(pwd):/source -w /source oror/rust-test cargo run`
3. `docker ps`

[Terminal Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HStgZ.png)

4. `ifconfig` to get my machine's IP address: `192.168.0.6`
5. `curl 192.168.0.6:8080` to connect to my rust web app

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

I've tried `localhost:8080` and I still get the same output.
What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you deploy the docker container? You should also check whether you really want `-p 8080:80 `.

Comment: I deployed it on my local machine. I tried running the docker container without `-p 8080:80`; the docker image ran on port 32768. I tried connecting to `192.168.0.6:32768` but got the same response

Comment: That port does not have to do with your server, you should still have to access it via port 8080.

Comment: Okay, I think I don't need the line `-p 8080:80` because my rust server listens on port 8080 and that port is exposed in the docker file but I still face the same issue

Comment: Try `-p 8080` instead.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is your web server is listening to requests from 127.0.0.1 (local interface) but from inside your container. From the container point of view, your host is outside so you need to listen to requests from 0.0.0.0, then it should works.

```
Iron::new(hello_world).http("0.0.0.0:8080").unwrap();
```

If you need to filter where your requests come from, I suggest you to do it from outside your container with a firewall or something like that.